# How to insert multiple MySQL table rows from a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm new to both PHP and MySQL and I have a pretty complicated task to do for my current know-how. It goes like this:

I'm trying to create a data-driven website with a hand made CMS that will allow a user with no knowledge of web design/web development to manage it. Where I'm stuck is when I try to create a query to handle the data inserted to the database. It is a bookstore and I'm inserting books in the database. I thought of creating 3 tables, one to store the books themselves, one to store the categories these books belong to (f.e. literature, mystery, fantasy, etc) and, since the relation between these two tables is many-to-many relationship, I also created a lookup table to link these two, using 2 columns populated with 2 foreign keys representing the IDs of the two tables.

The problem is I can't find how to insert multiple rows with same ID (the book ID) on one column and different second column (the category ID). The categories will be picked in an HTML form via checkboxes. I' ve seen in several posts here I need to make an array in PHP script to store the data from the checkboxes the user picked, but I have absolutely no clue on how to structure the query that will turn these checkboxes into multiple MySQL table rows.

I've seen people suggesting imploding the values, but that would store multiple values in one row, or am I mistaken? Because that is not what I want, I want (if f.e. the user checked 3 categories checkboxes) to create 3 rows in the lookup table.

Thanks in advance for your time seeing my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = array(1,2,3,4);
$bookId = 5;

foreach ($categories as $categoryId) {

    $data = array(
        'book_id' => (int)$bookId,
        'category_id' => (int)$categoryId
    );

    $query = "INSERT INTO `lookup` SET ";
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $fields[] = "`$field` = '$value'";
    }
    $fields = implode(', ', $fields);
    $query .= $fields;

    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Thing is I can't just declare the array for the categories, I need to get it through the HTML form, right now I am using a loop like this `echo("<input type='checkbox' name='row_tag[]' value='$tag_id' />".$tag_name."<br />");` to show them to the user. Any ideas how to turn them into an array?

Comment: if you have `name='row_tag[]'` in the form, you should get an array in PHP, like `array(1, 2, 3)`, which would be ok. Do something like `var_export($_POST['row_tag']);` to see what you are getting, exactly.

Comment: It seems I am getting NULL values and an unidentified index for row_tag. I tried to echo it inside the while loop that presents the category checkboxes to the HTML form after the checkboxs. Should I echo it elsewhere, or do something else?

Comment: does the form look ok? If you view-source on the form, can you see the values properly? Also, if you do not select any checbox, the $row_tag variable will be empty

Comment: So far the form looks OK, though I don't see anything when hovering over the checkboxes. And on the initial state the checkboxes should all be empty, no "checked" value should be applied. The user must check all he needs to be checked, he must check at least one though for the form to validate.

Comment: if you have the name and values ok, you should get them corectly in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You can build up an insert using implode to insert many rows. Something like this:-

```
<?php

$Category = 123;

$Books = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$sql = "INSERT INTO book_category_link(NULL, category_id, book_id)
        VALUES ($Category".implode("),($category", $Books).")";

?>
```

Or if you want to use the existing tables to get the ids then something like this:-

```
<?php

$Category = (123, 456, 789);

$Books = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$sql = "INSERT INTO book_category_link(NULL, category_id, book_id)
        SELECT NULL, categories.id, books.id
        FROM books
        CROSS JOIN categories
        WHERE books.id IN (".implode(",", $Books).")
        AND categories.id IN (".implode(",", $Category).")";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but since I am new to PHP, won't implode insert multiple values into one column? That's not what I need. I need 3 rows if 3 checkboxes are checked, 5 rows if 5 checks etc.

Comment: No, because you can put the separator and other columns in the 1st parm of the implode. Hence the 1st parm is "),($category"

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't insert into multiple tables in one MySQL command. You can however use transactions.

```
INSERT ...
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @mysql_variable_here;
INSERT INTO table2 (@mysql_variable_here, ...);
INSERT INTO table3 (@mysql_variable_here, ...);
```

if you want to add multiple rows inserted then u can use the syntax

```
INSERT INTO  table (col1, col2) VALUES ('value', 'value'), (value, 'value');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am not trying to insert into multiple tables with one query, I am trying to insert into one table multiple rows with one, or, if needed, multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. First you insert the the book into the `books` table and then [get the ID of it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Let's say for this example it is the ID `5`.

Lets say you have the following categorie id's from the checkboxes: `array(21, 42, 64);`
Now you can construct a query like this to insert them into the `lookup` table:

```sql
INSERT INTO `lookup` (book_id, category_id') VALUES (5, 21), (5, 42), (5, 64);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, will try it out and let you know!

Comment: It seems I don't get it how would the category ID's get assigned though from the HTML form... I have this: `echo("<input type='checkbox' name='row_tag[]' value='$tag_id' />".$tag_name."<br />\n");`in a while loop to show them inside the HTML form, is it correct? and if it is, how do I turn these values into $categories[] array?

Answer (score 0):

The very basic idea is to iterate a loop on the categories submitted and run an insert query containing category ID and book ID into the lookup table.

```
$bookID= $_POST['bookid'];
foreach ($categories as $category) {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO lookup(bookid,categoryid) values($bookID,$catetory)");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what is $nppkID? sorry for asking simple things, fundamendals to others, but I am really new to this...